# Reference: Invariant for comparators in collections

Tags: java, c++, language-lawyer, comparator

Consider the following Java example:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2};
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> a[i]));
pq.add(0);
pq.add(1);
a[1] = 0;
System.out.println(pq.peek()); // Prints 0
```

So, we insert elements into the queue, and then change the result of their comparison (initially `0` is less than `1`, and after `a[1] = 0` we have that `1` is less than `0`).
As I understand, in this case the behavior of the priority queue is unspecified (this is a typical mistake in implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm).
I say that the following invariant (contract?) is violated:

> If `x` and `y` are in the priority queue, then the result of their comparison must remain unchanged until one of these elements is removed from the priority queue.

What concerns me is that I can't find any mention of this in either C++ or Java documentation.
I guess both documentations assume that comparators are "immutable", i.e. the result of comparison of `x` and `y` never changes.
"Immutable" comparators are certainly a good practice (although I also didn't find any mention of that in the documentation), but not what happens in the above example.

I request a reference to either C++ or Java documentation which discusses the issue. I expect documentation to specify all the requirements to guarantee that the data structures works correctly, so it is very weird that I can't find this one. To conform with the SO expectations (namely that the answer still remains valid after the link dies), I think it also makes sense to paste the text from the link into the answer.

Comment: Consider adding language tag and providing code samples in the languages you have in mind. However, I believe that this question is pretty clear considering `std::priority_queue`, passing comparator that uses some vector `a`, and populating it as you explained. Fifth tag (very important here) might be [tag:language-lawyer], while [tag:contract] is almost certainly irrelevant.

Comment: I think immutability is implied by the Comparator [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). If it returns inconsistent results over time, none of its invariants will hold up.

Comment: @shmosel, I don't think the contract implies immutability. My understanding is that all of the expressions in the link must evaluate to true, e.g. `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` must evaluate to true at any point. This requirement holds.

Comment: @shmosel, although there is that note "This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception", so I'm less than confident that I understand what precisely the documentation says.

Comment: I guess I would say it's time-agnostic. A comparator is valid for any given window if its contract holds during that window. If you're looking at a single point in time, it may be valid for that moment. But if you're going to use it over some period of time, you need to respect the contract for that duration.

Comment: No, the requirement `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` is not fulfilled when you change the comparator while it is in use by a `PriorityQueue`. There are some `compare` calls before the change and some after and when you check the outcome of those calls, you will find that the required invariant does not hold. Likewise, the transitivity for the calls is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), the operations of `std::priority_queue` are defined in terms of `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap`.  See basically all of [priority.queue] 24.6.7.

The comparison you provide must be a strict weak ordering (in the mathematical sense); if it breaks said ordering, it isn't a valid strict weak ordering.

push/pop in turn specifies that the range it is operating on is a valid heap (with an extra element for push) with respect to that strict weak ordering.

As an example, [push.heap] 27.8.8.2/2 says the preconditions for `push_heap` are:

> **Preconditions**: The range `[first, last - 1)` is a valid heap with respect to `comp` and `proj`.
> For the overloads in namespace `std`, `RandomAccessIterator` meets the *Cpp17ValueSwappable* requirements ([swappable.requirements]) and the type of *first meets the *Cpp17MoveConstructible* requirements (Table 31) and the *Cpp17MoveAssignable* requirements (Table 33).

So if you make the container not be a valid heap by modifying the elements mid-way through using a priority queue, you violate the preconditions of push/pop, and the C++ standard does not constrain the behavior of the program anymore.  (Undefined behavior escape clause!)

If you modify the elements in such a way that the container still contains a valid heap, but one that is utterly different than the heap it was on the last time you interacted with it, you are 100% ok.

This is different than how `std::map`/`set` and `std::unordered_map`/`set` are defined, where it explicitly disallows messing with the ordering.

Container adapters in C++ are a bit strange.  It does mean they can be wrapped around your own utterly strange container and nothing strange happens.

Comment: Thank you! I think I don't understand last two paragraphs. 1) Where is messing with ordering disallowed (if it's mentioned at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map, I didn't understand that)? 2) For container adapters, I guess you refer too priority queue vs vector. What's do you mean by saying that vector is strange?

Comment: @Dmitry For your question (1) I don't know if it says it on cppreference, but here it is in the standard: [[associative.reqmts.general\]p3](https://wg21.link/associative.reqmts.general#3.sentence-4)

Comment: @Dmitry cppreference is not the standard, and does not in any way define what C++ is.  It is an easy to read reference manual maintained as a wiki.

Comment: @Dmitry So, the STL was a library added to the std library way back when C++ didn't exist yet.  During development of C++, templates where added to C, and people experimented with them.  A bunch of template libraries deemed high quality where bundled up into a library known as STL (standard template library).  The C++ standard then incorporated them into std, along side other features.  The 4 parts where containers, algorithms, std::string and container adapters.  Container adapters are templates that wrap a container and give it a different API.  priority_queue is a container adapter.

Comment: @Dmitry It takes as one of its arguments what underlying container it uses for storage.  The standard then defines how it repurposes that storage to produce the effects of the API.  The default container of std::priority_queue container adapter is a std::vector; but, if you wrote my::fancy_container, you could use that instead (if it satisfies the requirements of priority queue, which the standard describes).  The container adapters are often described far more concretely than containers are.